# JQUERY refreshing .val() after inserting in to database

Tags: php, jquery, html, refresh

How can I change the time in the registeration form when it returns after submission.

```
$("#leaveComment").find("input#time").val("<? echo time(); ?>");
```

after inserting into database (insert database is configured and working in file resources/lib/add-comment.php)?

[here is full code of needed jquery](http://paste.php.lv/6281064c6d1aa8b1e67ef5e2a03f47ae?lang=javascript)

and [here is PHP script for submit (add-comment.php file contents)](http://paste.php.lv/ac92cd4a149cd9d31bcdd3f9d49e4d3f?lang=php)

Comment: Use javascript to get the current date and time?

Comment: @ jrummell

You can't just trust the clock setting on the client side :)

Comment: PHP in this case (at least the way you're using it) will only ever set the value to the time that the page was processed, NOT the time the comment was left.

Answer (score 5):

if the return result is `json` :

```
$("#leaveComment").find("input#time").val(data.time);
```

or do simple `echo` inside `add-comment.php` :

```
echo time();
```

then :

```
$("#leaveComment").find("input#time").val(data);
```

Comment: I know that echo time(); is better for add-comment.php but then date will not returnet. I change content of question, please check it again!

Comment: please check second link, where are displayed add-comment.php content. This doesn`t work. At third submit date doesn`t return on list of comment. There is JSON data returning, but Your variant doesn`t work.

Comment: @MatīssCelmiņš still don't understand what do you mean, there no echo or date or time() ??

Comment: Ok, this $("#leaveComment").find("input#time").val(data.time);
doesn`t work, because on second submit JavaScript returns empty value. echo time(); doesn`t work, because there are more submited values instead of add-comment.php. Second variant do same operation too. Need another solution for this prolem!

Comment: @MatīssCelmiņš did you read my answer i said do an `echo` or use `json` format, the `data` must not be empty, i mean `add-comment.php` must return something

Comment: Sorry, second variant is working, time(); instead of add-comment.php and $("#leaveComment").find("input#time").val(data); instead of JavaScript! Thanks!